# Better way to write complex statement

Tags: c#, performance, if-statement, enums

Imagine you have int n and you have to make sure it isn't equal to certain numbers.

I would solve that like this:

```
int n = 5;
if (n != 4 && n != 11 && n != 1)
    do something..
```

The solution I'm looking for does it with enums, so:

```
int n = MyEnum.ValueThree;
if (n != MyEnum.ValueFour && n != MyEnum.ValueOne && n != MyEnum.ValueTen)
    do something..
```

There must some more performant or prettier way to write this.

Comment: With only 3 values to compare, none of the proposed alternatives will be more performant - and if they are prettier is a matter of taste. With a huge set of values, `HashSet<>.Contains()` will give best performance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use Array to solve the problem

```
int n = 5;
int[] NotAllowed = { 1, 4, 11 };
if (!NotAllowed.Contains(n))
    do something..
```

it's much prettier way to do your task :)

Comment: OP asks for a performant or prettier way. Some might think this is prettier, but it's certainly not more performant. You wouldn't be allowed to commit this in my repository :P

Answer (score 2):

You can have a List<int> and then use Syntactic Sugar (aka LINQ)

```
int n = 5; // or your way of getting value
var list = new List<int>() {9, 11, 17};
if(list.All(x=>x != n))
{
    // Do your stuff here
}
```

Comment: For performance - if the set to validate against is tooo big. May be you can change the list.All to Parallel.ForEach.

Answer (score 1):

It would also be nice to use the [Array.TrueForAll](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.trueforall?view=netcore-3.1#System_Array_TrueForAll__1___0___System_Predicate___0__) method.

```
int n = 5;
int[] values = {4, 11, 1}
if (Array.TrueForAll(values, e => e != n))
   do something..
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are planning on reusing the logic my suggestion would be creating a function on it. Also this approach will not limit you on the numbers of comparers.

```
public class ComparerClass
{
    private List<int> _parameters = new List<int>();
    private readonly int _baseNum;
    public Person(int baseNum, List<int> parameters))
    {
        _parameters = parameters;
        _baseNum = baseNum;
    }


    public bool IsNotEqualToAny()
    {
        return !_parameters.Contains(_baseNum);
    }
}
```

then on your program

```
var baseNum = //your base number to compare
var comparers = new List<int> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
var isNotInBetweenNumbers = new ComparerClas(baseNum, comparers).IsNotEqualToAny();

if (isNotInBetweenNumbers)
{
    //do something
}



//long part of code

var newComparers = new List<int> {2,3,4,5,7,9,10}
isNotInBetweenNumbers = new ComparerClass(baseNum, newComparers).IsNotEqualToAny();

if (isNotInBetweenNumbers)
{
    // new do something
}
```